# Can SQL Server 2000 replicate system databases and/or logins?

Tags: replication, sql-server

Can SQL Replication be used to publish SQL Server 2000 system databases to another SQL Server 2000 server, i.e master, model, msdb?

If this is not possible, what is the correct strategy for keeping SQL Logins synchronised (more specifically their passwords) between a publishing server and a subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use replication on system databases, as they are inherently server- (and instance-) specific.

To copy logins, have a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133

Comment: I saw that article, but it appears that both computers need to be domain members, which in my case they aren't. The subscription server is a new machine so I just restored the system databases then the databases to be replicated and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917706.aspx
 covers synchronizing logins between publisher and subscriber

Comment: I'll have a look at this but not sure if I'll be able to use due to the requirement for a shared folder. We're pretty heavily locked down.